# System environment variables not accessible in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux, and I have a bash script that I want to run that needs to access system environment variables. Specifically, I defined an environment variable on my system with the following command:

```
export SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN="Insert Token Here"
```

I then define a file called `slack.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN
```

I then run this script with `source ./slack.sh`. When I run this command, it just prints out a blank line - it's not getting the value of the environment variable.

I've tried different syntax in the .sh file for referencing the environment variable, like `"$SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN"` and `${SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN}` but same result. I've also run the script with `/slack.sh` and `. ./slack.sh` but same results.

How do I get my script to see `$SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN`?

Comment: are `slack.sh` and `slack_delete.sh` different files?

Comment: If `slack.sh` was saved with DOS line endings, then you are attempting to expand the variable `SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN\r`, not `SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN` (where `\r` represents the carriage-return of the CR/LF pair that terminates the line).

Comment: Confirm that the environment variable is present by running `env` from inside the script, or by appending some other character to the line (e.g., `echo $SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN x`), which will separate the variable name from the CR/LF pair. Using `echo ${SLACK_LEGACY_API_TOKEN}` should also be sufficient to keep the variable name from being "contaminated".

Comment: Apologies - slack_delete.sh was a typo. Should have said slack.sh. Edited.

Comment: Works for me, as long as it is executed in the same shell. Your problem seems to be the sentence "I defined an environment variable on my system". You don't define an environment variable for the system, just for a shell (and any sub-shells).

Comment: I tried it on my WSL, but instead of using an editor I wrote the `slack.sh` in `nano` and I see the value. I guess @chepner is right regarding CR/LF endings and that could be the root cause. Also if you want to use this variable preferably place it in `~/.bashrc` file if you need to access it next time.

Comment: If you edit files on Windows, you will often need to use `dos2unix` to fix them when you copy them to Linux.

Comment: @Shan-Desai It is more common to define environment variables *once*, in `.bash_profile`, based on the common use of starting one login shell from which other interactive shells inherit their environment.

Comment: Thanks all - got it working. @chepner is correct about the issue - the problems were resulting from saving the script in my Windows environment which must have been adding the carriage return. Defining the file entirely in WSL solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @chepner in the comments within my question, the issue was caused by defining the `.sh` file in my Windows environment. This results in the file being saved with DOS line endings which was causing the issues with the script. Redefining the file entirely within the Linux environment solved the problem.